# Invoice at admin panel, do not include custom discount and fee amount why is this happening?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have made a custom discount and fee module but when I create invoice at admin panel,invoice do not include custom discount and fee amount. I want to know from where i can change the custom discount and extra fee for payment in the admin module?

Answer (score 0):

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_new>
    <reference name="invoice_totals">
        <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_item" name="fee" template="fee/sales/order/total.phtml">
        </block>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_new>

<adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_updateqty>
    <reference name="invoice_totals">
        <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_item" name="fee" template="fee/sales/order/total.phtml">
        </block>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_updateqty>

<adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_view>
    <reference name="invoice_totals">
        <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_item" name="fee" template="fee/sales/order/total.phtml">
        </block>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_view>
```

You have to include layout xml update something like above in your adminhtml/layout. This will help you. Replace template path with yours. Hope this will help.